# Search filter on Array Angular 2

Tags: angular, treeview, navbar

I have a dynamic navigation bar with search functionality on top it

**Component.html**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Navigation search..." [(ngModel)]="searchString">
<li class="nav-item " *ngFor="let dir of directories">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
        <span class="title">{{ dir.name }}</span>
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" *ngFor="let file of dir.child">
        <li class="nav-item  ">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link ">
                <span class="title">{{file.name}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <navigation-bar [directories]="dir.child"></navigation-bar>
     </ul>
</li>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'navigation-bar',
    templateUrl: './app/home/navigationBar.component.html',    
})

export class NavigationBarComponent {
    @Input() directories: Array<Tree>;      
}

export class Tree{
    directories: any;
    constructor()
    {
        this.directories = [
        {
            name: 'parent1',
            child: [{
                name: 'child1',
                child: []
            },
            {
                name: 'child2',
                child: []
            }]
        },
        {
            name: 'parent2',
            child: {
                name: 'child1',
                child: []
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'parent2',
            child: [{
                name: 'child1',
                child: []
            },
            {
                name: 'child2',
                child: []
            }]
        }];
    }    
}
```

Now I want to search through the nav bar using the search string entered in the text box.

Is there any way to achieve above functionality for every character entered in the text box. It should filter the name property of the JSON object

Comment: can you create a plunker for the same , you can easily acheive this using keyup and using event emitters on the search  but a plunker will demonstrate this properly

Comment: It has so many dependencies, I have implemented Angular 2 in Asp.net Core

Comment: parent name or child name property?

Comment: Want to search on both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your input field:

```
<input (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value);">
```

On your component:

```
applyFilter(filter: String) {
    this.filteredArray = this.directories.filter(item => {
          if (item.name.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
            return true;
          }
        return false;
    }
    );
}
```

filteredArray is the array containing the items matching the filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom pipe to do this, advantage is that you can pass those keys needs to search. You can update below code for your needs. For example

```
<li *ngFor="let n of list | FilterPipe: queryString : searchableList ">
      {{n.name}} ({{n.age}})
</li>

 this.searchableList = ['name','age']
```

Pipe

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'FilterPipe',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, input: string,searchableList : any) {
        if (input) {
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            return value.filter(function (el: any) {
                var isTrue = false;
                for(var k in searchableList ){
                  if(el[searchableList[k]].toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1){
                    isTrue = true;
                  }
                  if(isTrue){
                    return el
                  }
                }

            })
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```